# React: Issue Updating Weather Details Based on Selected City

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm encountering an issue with my React application where I'm unable to update the weather details based on the selected city using the OpenWeatherMap API. Here's the setup:

1. I have a parent component `App` which manages the state of latitude and longitude.
2. Inside `App`, I have a child component `DisplayFetch` that fetches weather details based on latitude and longitude.
3. I also have another child component `SearchCities` inside `DisplayFetch`, which allows users to search for a city and updates the latitude and longitude when a city is selected.

The problem arises when I select a new city in `SearchCities`. Although the latitude and longitude are updated correctly in the `App` component, the weather details displayed in `DisplayFetch` do not update accordingly. The weather details remain associated with the previous location, rather than updating to the weather of the newly selected city.

I've ensured that the `updateLocation` function in the `App` component correctly updates the state of latitude and longitude, and it is being passed down to `DisplayFetch` and further to `SearchCities`. Additionally, I've confirmed that the `update` function (passed from `DisplayFetch` to `SearchCities`) is being called when a new city is selected, and it is correctly updating the latitude and longitude.

App:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import DisplayFetch from "./components/DisplayFetch";

export default function App() {
  const [latitude, setLatitude] = useState(null);
  const [longitude, setLongitude] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        console.log(position.coords.latitude);
        console.log(position.coords.longitude);
        setLatitude(position.coords.latitude);
        setLongitude(position.coords.longitude);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error("Error getting current geolocation:", error);
      }
    );
  }, []);

  const updateLocation = (lat, long) => {
    setLatitude(lat);
    setLongitude(long);
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex items-center justify-center h-screen bg-darkSlate">
      <div>
        {latitude} {longitude}
      </div>
      {latitude !== null && longitude !== null ? (
        <DisplayFetch
          latitude={latitude}
          longitude={longitude}
          updateLocation={updateLocation}
        />
      ) : (
        <p>Loading...dasdasdasdasdas</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

DisplayFetch:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import WeatherBox from "./WeatherBox";
import { CiLocationOn } from "react-icons/ci";
import { AsyncPaginate } from "react-select-async-paginate";
import SearchCities from "./SearchCities";

const DisplayFetch = ({ latitude, longitude, updateLocation }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&appid=MYAPI`
      );
      // Replace with your API endpoint
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Network response was not ok.");
      }
      const data = await response.json();
      setData(data);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error.message);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      {loading ? (
        <p>Loading...</p>
      ) : error ? (
        <p>Error: {error}</p>
      ) : (
        <div className="bg-paleBlue p-8 rounded-lg shadow-lg flex flex-col">
          <div className="relative border border-solid border-gray-300 rounded-md mb-4">
            <div>
              {latitude} {longitude}
            </div>
            <SearchCities
              latCity={latitude}
              longCity={longitude}
              update={updateLocation} // Pass updateLocation here
            />
            <div className="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-2"></div>
          </div>
          <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4">
            <WeatherBox title="Min Temp" value={`${data.main.temp_min}°C`} />
            <WeatherBox title="Max Temp" value={`${data.main.temp_max}°C`} />
            <WeatherBox
              title="Feels Like"
              value={`${data.main.feels_like}°C`}
            />
            <WeatherBox title="Pressure" value={`${data.main.pressure} hPa`} />
            <WeatherBox title="Humidity" value={`${data.main.humidity}%`} />
            <WeatherBox title="Wind Speed" value={`${data.wind.speed} m/s`} />
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default DisplayFetch;
```

SearchCities:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { AsyncPaginate } from "react-select-async-paginate";
import { geoApiOptions, GEO_API_URL } from "../components/api";
import DisplayFetch from "./DisplayFetch";

const SearchCities = ({ latCity, longCity, update }) => {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState(null);

  const loadOptions = (inputValue) => {
    return fetch(
      `${GEO_API_URL}/cities?minPopulation=1000&namePrefix=${inputValue}`,
      geoApiOptions
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        return {
          options: response.data.map((city) => {
            return {
              value: `${city.latitude} ${city.longitude}`,
              label: `${city.name}, ${city.countryCode}`,
            };
          }),
        };
      });
  };

  const handleOnChange = (searchData) => {
    setSearch(searchData);

    console.log(latCity);
    console.log(longCity);
    if (searchData) {
      const [lat, long] = searchData.value.split(" ");
      update(lat, long);
    } else {
      // Clear the latitude and longitude when no city is selected
      update(null, null);
    }
    console.log(latCity);
    console.log(longCity);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <AsyncPaginate
        placeholder="Search for city"
        debounceTimeout={600}
        value={search}
        onChange={handleOnChange}
        loadOptions={loadOptions}
      />
      <>
        <div>
          {latCity} from search city{longCity}
        </div>
      </>
    </>
  );
};

export default SearchCities;
```

Can someone find where I am going wrong?

Comment: The `useEffect` hook is missing dependencies. Voting to close as "not reproducible or was caused by typo". Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the dependencies array in your [useEffect](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#useeffect).

```
 useEffect(() => {
  fetchData();
 }, [latitude, longitude, updateLocation]);
```

This will trigger the fetchData() function on changes of any of this variables. Adjust accordingly (maybe you need the dependency only on updateLocation).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the fetch function inside the `useEffect` you are calling it one time only, but you need to call everytime there is a change in lat and long.

Inside DisplayFetch component you need to add dependencies (lat and long) to the `useEffect`, and you can conditionally re-fetch if there are lat and long.

Here is how you do it

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (latitude && longitude) fetchData();
  }, [latitude, longitude]);
```

I created a codesandbox with mock data and mock fetch. You can check it here
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/flamboyant-tesla-t3mmm5

You can fork the codesandbox in order to keep testing if you want.